# Defining a treein Go without type erasure

Tags: go, tree, variant

I'm trying to implement a tree with `strings` for edges and some `Leafs` for leafs.

My naive approach was to define

```go
type Leaf int

type Node interface {
    map[string]Node | Leaf
}
```

Which results in `cannot use type Node outside a type constraint: interface contains type constraints`

In C++ I would use `std::variant` for this: store values from a set of types without loosing static typing. `go-ext/variant` looks like designed for something else.

`spf13/viper` goes full on python in this case and just uses:

```go
map[string]interface{}
```

But i keep reading from different sources that erasing types is `not idiomatic go`

In the end there is always a clumsy:

```go
type Leaf int

type Node struct {
    Tree
    value *Leaf
}

type Tree map[string]Node
```

**What is the `idiomatic go` solution to this problem?**

Comment: An important detail is that this is not type erasure, go always retains the dynamic type of values in interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Below is one way of doing it:

The problem is that you can't really have a map that contains nodes and leaves without type erasure, but you can have a map that contains nodes, some of which can be leaves. So a tree that uses a leaf type parameter can be constructed as:

```
type Node[T any] interface {
    GetChildren() map[string]Node[T]
}

type NodeImpl[T any] struct {
    children map[string]Node[T]
}

func (n NodeImpl[T]) GetChildren() map[string]Node[T] {
    return n.children
}

// A leaf is also a node
type Leaf[T any] interface {
    Node[T]
    GetValue() T
}


type LeafImpl[T any] struct {
    value T
}

func (l LeafImpl[T]) GetValue() T {
    return l.value
}
func (l LeafImpl[T]) GetChildren() map[string]Node[T] { return nil }
```

The you can do:

```
root := NodeImpl[int]{children: make(map[string]Node[int])}
nd := NodeImpl[int]{children: make(map[string]Node[int])}
root.children["b"] = nd
root.children["a"] = LeafImpl[int]{value: 1}
```

You can use type assertion to see if a node in the tree is a leaf:

```
leaf, ok:=root.GetChildren()["a"].(Leaf[int])
```